# SciPy: What are the arguments in `scipy.special.fresnel(x[, out1, out2])`?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, fresnel

I am trying to plot a clothoid function using SciPy. [Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.fresnel.html#scipy.special.fresnel) is the syntax for the Fresnel integrals but I cannot understand what are the arguments `x`, `out1`, `out2` in `scipy.special.fresnel(x[, out1, out2])`? Formulas in the description are about `t` and `z`, which are not in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments `out1` and `out2` are optional.  You can use

```
s, c = fresnel(x)
```

The argument `z` shown in the docstring is the `x` argument.  That is an unfortunate discrepancy--the docstring should be consistent with the function signature.

The arguments `out1` and `out2` can be used if you already have arrays in which you want to put the results of the function call.  This allows you to save memory by reusing existing arrays.

Note that the scipy implementation of the function scales the argument by pi/2.  See the notes about this in the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

This script will generate the first plot shown in the wikipedia article:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import fresnel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 5.0, 201)
ss, cc = fresnel(t / np.sqrt(np.pi / 2))
scaled_ss = np.sqrt(np.pi / 2) * ss
scaled_cc = np.sqrt(np.pi / 2) * cc
plt.plot(t, scaled_cc, 'g--', t, scaled_ss, 'r-', linewidth=2)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains some things.

Comment: By the way, I do not need scaling. And I use a coefficient `a` in front of `cc` and `ss` to get the correct angle (a multiple of `pi / 2`) for the clothoid tail: `plt.plot(a * cc, a * ss, 'r-o', linewidth = 2)`. So, for `a = 1` I get the ending angle `pi / 2`.